# Make a delegated jQuery Auto-complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-delegate

I am using the following code to create an auto-complete textbox. The jQuery is as follows.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#items .slno" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php'
   });
});
```

The HTML is as follows.

```
<table id="items">
     <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">-</a></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="slslno" class="slno"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
            <!--  <td><span class="price"></span></td>-->
            <td class="price"></td>
            <a class="add" id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">+</a> </tr>

</table>
```

The Auto-complete works for the first row. However, when the second row is created by clicking on the "Add a row" button in the above code (Its all working fine), the Auto_complete just isn't working on the subsequent rows. I sorted out that I would need a delegated handler for that. SO how can I convert my current jQuery selector to a delegated one?

I Kinda wrote it like the following based on the answer, but it's still not working.

```
   $('#items').delegate('#items .slno','keyup', function () {   

  $(this).autocomplete({
         source: 'search.php'
    });

  });
```

Then I went on to use the following.

```
  $(function(){
  $('#items').on('.slno','keyup.autocomplete', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source : 'search.php'
    });
  });
});
```

and it too failed. How do I achieve this?

## UPDATE

In the above example, the ordering of the event was messed up. Just needed touse the proper syntax

```
$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function,map)
```

Which makes my code look like the following.

```
  $(function(){
  $('#items').on('keyup.autocomplete','.slno', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source : 'search.php'
    });
  });
});
```

And it did the task !!!

Comment: class="slno" is not implemented on other columns

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to say

Comment: The class, if the OP is cloning the row, is added to the row @abhi

Comment: yes it definitely is. So what?

Comment: `autocomplete` is not an event, so it makes no sense to try and use it with `.on`. Just initialize it for the new row that you add, when you are adding it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked for me like a charm.

```
$(function(){
      $('#items').on('keyup.autocomplete','.slno', function(){
        $(this).autocomplete({
          source : 'search.php'
        });
      });
    });
```